# Reading node.js documentation on the command line

Tags: node.js

I'm relatively new to node and the other day when hacking on it without a 'net connection, I wanted to read the documentation of the `http` module from the command line. In Python or Perl, I just use `pydoc` or `perldoc` and the name of the module I want to read documentation for, but for the life of me, I couldn't figure out how to do this for node.js and now, reading about this online doesn't seem to shed much light on my tiny little brain.

So how do I read (install?) node documentation, particularly for non-core modules such as angular, particularly if I'm in an old farmhouse in the middle of nowhere and no 'net connection?

Comment: https://github.com/trentm/nodedoc

Answer (score 3):

Check out [wat](https://github.com/dthree/wat), a project I made to do just the above.

It's currently in beta, but should public release this month, and it currently supports Node.js documentation on the command line.